# Horizontal Menu item with Horizontal SubMenu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been struggling with the WPF Menu and I simply cannot achieve what I want to.

I tried changing default styling on the Menu and MenuItem control, but this turned out terrible. I then tried styling it by making use of control templates, however, I think I came to realization that my WPF skill just aren't there yet.

Here is a picture of my desired result:

[image]

Is there anyone that can maybe point me in the right direction? Or maybe assist me with some xaml that will give my desired result?

Comment: look at that I hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813348/horizontal-menu-with-horizontal-submenu-in-wpf

Comment: Thanks, but have a look on my picture, i want extra one more menuitem

Answer (score 1):

for adding multiple rows use stack panel

```
<MenuItem Header="_ITEM2">
                    <MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </MenuItem.ItemsPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <MenuItem Header="_SUBMENU11" IsCheckable="true"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_SUBMENU12" IsCheckable="true"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_SUBMENU13" IsCheckable="true"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <MenuItem Header="_SUBMENU21" IsCheckable="true"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_SUBMENU22" IsCheckable="true"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="_SUBMENU23" IsCheckable="true"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Separator/>
</MenuItem>
```